# Difference between different memory storage parameters

Tags: memory, operating-system

I simply want to know what is the difference between the words:

Allocated memory, free memory, Available memory, capacity and used memory.

lets suppose we have 2 GB storage and it has 200mb data.

Answer (score 1):

[Allocated memory](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/A/allocated_memory.html):

> Is the amount of RAM allotted to different programs and applications.
>   The amount of allocated memory is preset when you install your program
>   and varies depending on how large the application is.

[Free memory](https://superuser.com/a/694867/375562):

> Free ram is ram that hasn't been allocated yet.

[Available memory](http://www.reviversoft.com/blog/2013/11/what-is-the-difference-between-available-and-free-physical-memory/):

> This number is equal to cached memory plus free memory. Cached memory:This is
>   where things can become confusing. The objective of memory is to make
>   things accessible more quickly. To this end, Windows loads items into
>   memory that aren’t needed yet, but might be later. This is cached
>   memory. It has stuff in it, but it can be emptied if it is needed by
>   one of your programs.

[Capacity](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/320202-30-maximum-capacity):

> RAM capacity is a physical hardware limitation.

**Used memory**:
Used memory means the amount of ram that an application currently using from the allocated memory of its.

**EDIT:** *Adding demonstration*

Suppose that you have 2G of ram on your device:

*Capacity  :* 2G --> Your whole memory
*Allocated :* 1.5G --> suppose that your current apps are allocated 1.5 currently
*Free      :* 0.5G
*Cached    :* 0.3G --> reserved from allocated, This memory is cached to increase speed of memory usage
*Available :* 0.8G --> Free + Cached
*Used      :* 0.2G --> from allocated, let's say your applications are currently using the 0.2G of 1.5G allocated where 0.3 is cached and 1.0 is "allocated and not used"

Comment: I know these definitions.Can you elaborate it in figures.
Suppose I have 2GB hard disk.Then what the values of all these parameters.

Comment: can we define used memory in terms of others.I mean can we calculate used memory from others???

Comment: update: yes; `used: ("allocated" - "cached" - "allocated and not used")`

Comment: used memory = allocated memory - free memory
is it right??(if we not taking cache into scene)

Comment: No, as I described: used: ("allocated" - "cached" - "allocated and not used"), free is not allocated memory but used is a portion of allocated memory

Comment: what will be "allocated and not used" ??
is it not free??
or used memory  = capacity - free (if there is no cache)
I am little bit confused now

Comment: Let's say your apps allocated 1.5 of 2G, this is initial allocation, the OS feeds your applications from allocated, and other newly opened apps will use the free amount; the OS will allocate from 0.5G free for the newly opened apps. "Allocated and not used" means, as I said your OS allocate an amount of ram for your currently running apps, so there will be a portion which are filled by your apps and another portion which is waiting to be used, which is also located in "Allocated"

Comment: My last one: 
 used memory = capacity - free (if there is no cache).
it also not true, right?

Comment: Yes, OS first allocates an expected amount of ram for the apps currently opened, it's like you are inviting your children to your home and preparing a dinner for'em but you assume the amount of the dinner because you don't know if they are very hungry or not hungry; when they come you give them the food, they eat according to their needs, if they need more you go to the kitchen and prepare (allocate) more food, if the dinner is too much for your children you thorw it into garbage and the garbage goes to recycling factories to use the materials again, like the allocated memory is freed in OS